# Add onChange and generic inputs in custom component registered with React Hook Form v7

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I would like to have a custom component for a password input with eye icon, as follows:

```
type FormValues = {
    email: string;
    fullName: string;
    password: string;
    confirmPassword: string;
};

type PasswordInputProps = {
    name: string;
    value: string;
    register: UseFormRegister<FormValues>;
    // onChange: () => void;
}

export default function PasswordInput({
    name,
    value,
    register,
    // onChange
}: PasswordInputProps) {
    const [passwordShown, setPasswordShown] = useState(false);

    const togglePassword = () => {
        setPasswordShown(!passwordShown);
    };

    return (
        <Styled.Container>
            <AuthStyled.Input
                type={passwordShown ? "text" : "password"}
                value={value}
                {...register(name as keyof FormValues)}
                name={name}
            // onChange={onChange}
            />
            <Styled.Eye onClick={togglePassword}>
                {!passwordShown ? <BsEye /> : <BsEyeSlash />}
            </Styled.Eye>
        </Styled.Container>
    );
}
```

I have managed to register it using `react-hook-form` v7, but cannot seem to find a way to add `onChange` behavior or to make it generic and not bound to `FormValues` (for example, that FormValues is for Registration, but would like to have the same field in the Login Page).

Its usage is like this:

```
<PasswordInput
    name="confirmPassword"
    value={confirmPassword}
    register={register}
    // onChange={(e) => setConfirmPassword(e.target.value)}
/>
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2):

Your `onChange` type should use value `ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> | undefined`

```
type ComponentType = {
  onChange: ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> | undefined
} 

...

function Component({onChange}: ComponentType) {

...

  return (

    ...

    <MyTextInput 
      onChange={onChange}
    />
    
    ...

  )
}
```

EDIT: forgot to show usage:

```
import MyComponent from '....'

....

function handleOnChange(e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
  console.log(e.target.value)
}

return (
  ...

  <MyComponent
    onChange={(e) => {console.log(e.target.value)}}
    # or
    onChange={handleOnChange}
  />
)
```

Comment: That works. Thanks. Do you have any insights on how to make the component accept string literals outside of FormValues? Maybe with generic type T extending react-hook-form FieldValues?

Comment: I don't know if I understood right but you can extend and override types `type a = {prop: number, otherProp: string}` and `type b = {prop: string} & a`. Is this what you need?

Answer (score 0):

The answer I found for handling both onChange and form agnostic was:

```
type PasswordInputProps<T extends FieldValues> = {
    name: Path<T>;
    // value: string;
    register: UseFormRegister<T>;
    onChange: ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> | undefined;
}

export default function PasswordInput<T extends FieldValues>({
    name,
    register,
    onChange
}: PasswordInputProps<T>) {
    const [passwordShown, setPasswordShown] = useState(false);

    const togglePassword = () => {
        setPasswordShown(!passwordShown);
    };

    return (
        <Styled.Container>
            <AuthStyled.Input
                type={passwordShown ? "text" : "password"}
                // value={value}
                {...register(name)}
                name={name}
                onChange={onChange}
            />
            <Styled.Eye onClick={togglePassword}>
                {!passwordShown ? <BsEye /> : <BsEyeSlash />}
            </Styled.Eye>
        </Styled.Container>
    );
}
```